# Centering checkbox and text label with gravity = center

Tags: android

Is there an easy way to center the `checkbox` with it's text. I tried setting `Gravity = Center`, but it come out like the picture below. I want the `checkbox` to move to the center of the layout where the text is.

[image]

Here is the XML. The checkbox takes up the full width of the horizontal linear layout. I've set it's gravity = center, but the checkbox stays on the left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".EnterPipeIEActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/add_pipe_ie_title"
                android:textSize="35sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/channelized_pipes"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="CheckBox" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this part with following code:-

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Your checkbox will come in the center with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
</LinearLayout>
```